# Event List in WP

Tags: wordpress, civievent

Sorry for the noob question, but using Wordpress 6.4.3 & CiviEvent (5.67.2), how do you show an up-to-date list of upcomming events within wordpress?

I see how I could include the event shortcode into a specific page (I presume to have a pretty url), and also the generated event link with the example.org/civicrm/event/info/... url.  I also see a way to download an ics file, exporting existing events, but this doesn't allow pulling new events.

If there were a ical url, I could at least sync that with a google calendar and then show that on the webpage.

Edit-- Thanks, Coleman! Below is an image of event list on front end-- highlighting 2 formatting issues still a bit off:
[image: Image of event list on front end-- highlighting issue still a bit off]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is with SearchKit.

Here is documentation about how to create an Upcoming Events list using SearchKit:
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/searching/searchkit/example-upcoming-events/

Comment: Thank you -- I've got this setup and showing on the front end -- Added image of how it looks.  

Just two things still off --it seems that marking 'New Line' did not force items to a new line.  Also, I'd love to have a bit more space or a horizontal rule between events.  It appears I can uploads a code file, but that seems extreme for a Line break or a horizontal rule...

Comment: The "New Line" option definitely should force a line-break unless something in your theme prevents it. Try enabling that option for every field.
To add a tag like `<hr>` you can use the "rewrite" option + "allow html" option.

Comment: The new line is definitely not applying correctly. I have it marked for every line. 

Additionally, selecting allow html and rewrite text to incorporate html did not seem to make and difference.  I tried <hr), <br> and <p></p>.   It seems to preview ok (except <hr>) but doesn’t show on the front end that way.

Comment: Ok -- So after some more testing, if I use the URL created in FormBuilder Page Route, is shows the included HTML correctly.  If its dropped by short code directly into the content a WP page (in either Glutenberg blocks or the classic editor) it does not.  This was using the default WP 2024 theme.

Comment: Well I can't see your site, but I'm guessing the shortcode outputs the correct markup but it isn't styled well by your frontend theme.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative is to use the Event Organiser WP extension with its companion EO CiviCRM from Christian Wach like here https://smc-cse.fr/petit-dejeuner-thematiques/ (dynamic content that might be empty sometimes). It depends on your goal and the way you want to expose your upcoming events. It needs a bit of theming but we've been using it since years and are very happy.